# How to make a Meteor Collection non reactive depending on a url?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Hi I am building a magnetic poetry game with meteor which I am pretty green with.

http://test-magnets.meteor.com/

Currently it is collaborative it works great.  I am now trying to have it so that you can play privately without people messing with your poems.  I used Iron Router to generate a url based on the userID

router.js

```
Router.map(function() {
this.route('home', {
    path: '/'
});
var user = Meteor.userId();
this.route('private', {
    path: '/' + user
   });
});
```

I had the idea of using a fridgeId within the magnets.  On the home collaborative are the fridgeId is 1.  When you click on create my own, it changes the fridgeId to the same as the userId.  I am assuming I need to do some sort of publishing and subscribing based on the fridgeId but not sure how to.

this switches the fridgeId to the user id

```
  'click #new-board': function() {
    var user = Meteor.userId();
    var magnet = Magnets.findOne();
    Magnets.update({_id: magnet._id}, {$set: {fridgeId: user}});
    return Magnets.find({fridgeId: user});
}
```

then this sets the fridgeId back to 1 on the home page

```
Template.private.events = {
   'click #group-play': function() {
    var magnet = Magnets.findOne();
    Magnets.update({_id: magnet._id}, {$set: {fridgeId: 1}});
    return Magnets.find({fridgeId: 1});
  }
};
```

current subscribe and publish

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

Meteor.subscribe('magnets', function() {
    return Magnets.find();
 });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('magnets', function() {
    return Magnets.find();
  });
 }
```

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

-John

Comment: I have this same functionality in Meteor Blocks: https://github.com/stubailo/meteor-blocks you can see some of the functions in https://github.com/stubailo/meteor-blocks/blob/master/client/routes.js (In my project, "Scene" is like "Fridge" and "Box" is like "Magnet")

Answer (score 2):

```
return Magnets.find({fridgeId: user},{reactive: false});
```

Comment: would I use this in the the subscription block or within the router?  thanks for the response

Comment: You should create this on client, this makes sure there are no hooks 'observeChanges' attached