# How to make some page not automatically refresh in meteor?

Tags: meteor

For example, I have a postList page, which shows all posts. If somebody post a new post, this page got automatically refreshed.

This will get users confused.

So I want to make this page not automatically refresh, but inform the user: "there are new posts, click reload button to refresh". something like this.

How to do it in Meteor

Comment: Have not came up an idea.

Comment: Think some idea then come back to us ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28075985/how-to-make-a-meteor-collection-non-reactive-depending-on-a-url

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16038022/5144529) shows two different ways to disable reactivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple, the refresh happens because you have reactive dependency in your case probably a helper that returns a cursor which is reactive by default like this

```
Template.any.helpers({
  Posts: function () {
    return Posts.find();
  }
})
```

To disable reactivity use `Posts.find({}, {reactive: false});`